# Custom Model Binder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I'd like to create a custom model binder.

Let's say there're 20 properties. I need manualy bind only five of them. I'd like to bind the other 15 properties automatic like the default binder does.

Is this somehow possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, the very least thing you can do is inherit `DefaultModelBinder`, override the `BindModel(...)` method and use `base.BindModel(...)` for whatever you want. After that just provide your own binding logic for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem few days ago and I have solved it by filling the default properties **inside the constructor**. In this way I just pass the model without any problem even if I don't have an "Author" field:

```
public class Post
{
    private string title;
    private string author;
    private string content;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

    public string Author
    {
        get { return author; }
        set { author = value; }
    }

    public string Content
    {
        get { return content; }
        set { content = value; }
    }

    public Post()
    {
        this.author = "Davis";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here [model binder in MVC](https://www.sharpencode.com/article/MVC/model-binders) is a great example for creating custom model binder and how exactly model binder works in asp.net MVC.